# Java JXL API how to add Decimal separator for numbers

Tags: java, excel, jxl

i'm using jxl to export a small jtable to excel, and i choose JXL API to realize my objective, everything is going well.
but i still have a small problem about number format :

how can i add a decimal separator like in the example below:

```
------------------------
2365897412
------------------------
```

TO

```
------------------------
2 365 897 412
------------------------
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberFormat nf=new NumberFormat("#,###.###");                   // this format constraints the number upto 3 decimal points
WritableCellFormat cf2obj=new WritableCellFormat(nf);
numobj=new Number(2,1,3698745896546.353454,cf2obj);
sheet.addCell(numobj);
```

and the output in the excel sheet look like this

```
3 698 745 896 546,35
```

thanks

Comment: You mean jxl.write.NumberFormat (not java.text.NumberFormat)